# generate all unique triplets

Tags: python, random, combinatorics

there is a series of triplets:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15]]
```

(can be longer than that). They are all unique.

**Q:** What is the efficient way of generating  all possible combinations of these triplets such that none of the items that have met before, 'meet' again?

So for instance in this sequence none of triplets contain any items that encountered before:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15]]
[[1, 5, 9], [4, 8, 12], [7, 11, 15], [10, 14, 3],[2, 6, 13]]
[[1, 4, 7], [5, 8, 11], [9, 12, 15], [10, 13, 2],[14, 3, 6]]
```

but this one would not work:

```
[[1, 5, 9], [4, 6, 12], [7, 11, 15], [10, 14, 3],[2, 8, 13]]
```

because `4` and `6` from the second triplet have been in the same triplet before, specifically in `[4, 5, 6]` of the first record

I think that it can be done by picking random triplets from initial sequence using `random.sample(l, 3)` and then check if this triplet has not been used before, but it looks pretty unefficient and I wonder if there is a nicer way.

**UPDATE:::**

I realised that it makes sense to post a code that being ugly and inefficient still works, just to illustrate what I am talking about:

```
import random
import itertools

z = list(range(1, 10))
group_size = 3
superset = list()



def check_not_met(x):
    for i in superset:
        if set(x).issubset(set(i)):
            return False
    return True


def check_not_anyone_met(x):
    for i in itertools.combinations(x, 2):
        if not check_not_met(i):
            return False
    return True


subsession_matrices = list()


def generating_subsession(seq):
    subglobal = list()
    while seq:
        x = a[-group_size:]
        if check_not_anyone_met(x):
            subglobal.append(x)
        else:
            return False
        del seq[-group_size:]
    return subglobal

for j in range(10000):
    a = z.copy()
    random.shuffle(a)
    subsession_matrix = generating_subsession(a)
    if not subsession_matrix:
        continue
    else:
        subsession_matrices.append(subsession_matrix)
        superset.extend(subsession_matrix)

print(subsession_matrices)
```

and the output is:

```
[[3, 7, 1], [8, 2, 4], [6, 5, 9]]
[[8, 1, 9], [3, 5, 2], [7, 6, 4]]
[[3, 8, 6], [1, 4, 5], [7, 2, 9]]
[[8, 5, 7], [1, 2, 6], [3, 9, 4]]
```

Comment: If you want all possible combinations, it's better to be systematic than random.

Comment: You have 15! = 1 307 674 368 000 solutions

Comment: @Indent, that's not true since there are limitations

Comment: You don't want a PARTIAL triplets exist in another previous WHOLE triplet ? [4,6,12] don't exists in your first list, just a PART of the triplet - (the part is any couple of item?)

Answer (score 1):

OK this began as a comment but it was too big to be useful.

First of all by your definition there isn't a unique combination. Let me explain:

Since, you don't want to repeat any 2 numbers that have already appeared in a triplet the order by which they appear matters and change the combination.

An example to make it clear:

Given you start with:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

one possible sequence (different than yours) could be:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
[[1, 5, 10], [4, 8, 12], [7, 11, 15], [9, 14, 3],[ 2, 6, 13]]
```

(simply swap `9` for `10` in your second combination). This though makes `1` and `5`  unusable again in the same triplet so in that sequence your second combination

```
[[1, 5, 9], [4, 8, 12], [7, 11, 15], [10, 14, 3],[2, 6, 13]]
```

cannot appear in my sequence.

So, how do you define unique? There is a problem in your definition I think. I am not even sure that the order makes any difference in the length of the sequence.

> check if this triplet has not been used before

If you are not interested in a unique sequence but rather your want your limitation to apply to a sequence and get as many combinations as possible then the above won't work. You should check if 2 numbers are contained in a triplet not if a triplet has appeared before. Your criterion will fail to identify that the combination

```
[[1, 5, 9], [4, 7, 13], [8, 11, 15], [10, 14, 3], [2, 6, 12]]
```

is unacceptable although all triplets haven't appear before.

Hope this helps. Anyway, If I misunderstood something make an edit.

Comment: I agree, the word 'unique' is misleading, you are right. I added an example of (bad) code just to illustrate the idea

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively fill in each number to a list of triplets one by one while keeping track of the numbers each number has seen in a dict of sets, and return the combination if it manages to fill in all the numbers. Use a `while` loop to keep doing it until no more combination can be found:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def unique(items, size=3):
    def find_unique(items, size, seen, filled):
        filled_set = set(item for group in filled for item in group)
        if len(filled_set) == len(items):
            return filled, seen
        candidates = items - filled_set
        if not filled or len(filled[-1]) == size:
            filled.append([])
        for incumbent in filled[-1]:
            candidates -= seen[incumbent]
        new_seen = deepcopy(seen)
        new_filled = deepcopy(filled)
        for candidate in candidates:
            for incumbent in new_filled[-1]:
                new_seen[incumbent].add(candidate)
            new_seen[candidate].update(filled[-1])
            new_filled[-1].append(candidate)
            combinations, real_seen = find_unique(items, size, new_seen, new_filled)
            if combinations:
                return combinations, real_seen
            del new_filled[len(filled):]
            del new_filled[-1][len(filled[-1]):]
            for incumbent in new_filled[-1]:
                new_seen[candidate].remove(incumbent)
                new_seen[incumbent].remove(candidate)
        return None, None

    combinations = [items]
    seen = {}
    for group in items:
        for item in group:
            seen.setdefault(item, set()).update(group)
    while True:
        combination, seen = find_unique(seen.keys(), size, seen, [])
        if not combination:
            break
        combinations.append(combination)
    return combinations
```

so that:

```
unique([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]])
```

would return:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]],
 [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 10, 13], [6, 11, 14], [9, 12, 15]],
 [[1, 5, 9], [2, 4, 10], [3, 6, 15], [7, 11, 13], [8, 12, 14]],
 [[1, 6, 8], [2, 7, 14], [3, 9, 11], [4, 12, 13], [5, 10, 15]],
 [[1, 10, 14], [2, 11, 15], [3, 4, 8], [5, 7, 12], [6, 9, 13]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a recursive function:

```
d = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15]]
def create_triplet(nums, original, current = []):
  if len(current) == 3:
    yield sorted(current)
  else:
    for i in nums:
      yield from create_triplet(nums, original, current+[i])

_original = [d]
def triplets(source, current=[]):
  if len(current) == len(d):
     _original.append(current)
     yield current
  else:
     _flattened, seen = [i for b in current for i in b], []
     _options = list(create_triplet([i for i in source if i not in current], _original))
     for i in _options:
       if i not in seen and all(all(c not in b for c in i) for b in current) and all(i not in c for c in _original):
          _test = current+[i]
          if all(all(sum(h in c for h in i) < 2 for i in _test for c in b) for b in _original):
            yield from triplets(source, current=_test)
            seen.append(i)

_ = list(triplets([i for b in d for i in b]))
print(_original)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 10, 13], [6, 11, 14], [9, 12, 15]]
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 4, 10], [3, 6, 15], [7, 11, 13], [8, 12, 14]]
[[1, 6, 8], [2, 7, 14], [3, 9, 11], [4, 12, 13], [5, 10, 15]]
[[1, 10, 14], [2, 11, 15], [3, 4, 8], [5, 7, 12], [6, 9, 13]]
```

Comment: This incorrectly produces many combinations where items have met before. For example, `[3, 10, 13]` appears in both the second and the third combinations in your sample output, and `12` and `14` have met in both `[9, 12, 14]` in the second combination and `[6, 12, 14]` in the third combination..

Comment: @blhsing I was under the impression that for any two or three items in each combination sublist, those items could not appear together in any sublist of the original input. Does that apply to all sequences being generated? (each sequence generated is based-off of the previous)

Comment: Yes, each sequence generated is based-off of (all of) the previous, as evident from the OP's description and sample output.